# Problems with Google Firestore collectionGroup - whereArrayContains

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on an Android App written in Java.
I'm trying to query for documents in Cloud Firestore using **collectionGroup** and **whereArrayContains**.

My structure in Cloud Firestore looks like this:

```
Teams (collection)
  - teamUUID (document)
  - reservations(collection)
     - reservationDate (document)
     - places (collection)
         - userUUIDs (array of strings) 
               -> one entry ->"vQn9vbWzTtcsB71hgPBhX2uWBuI3"
         - placeID (document)
```

[partial screenshot of the structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieMHt.png)

I want to get all documents in the collection *places*, where the *userUUIDs* field contains a specific string. My code for this is the following:

```
db.collectionGroup("places")
                    .whereArrayContains("userUUIDs", 
                       "vQn9vbWzTtcsB71hgPBhX2uWBuI3")
                    .get()
                    .addOnSuccessListener(queryDocumentSnapshots -> {
                           Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments().size()));
                           if (queryDocumentSnapshots.isEmpty()) {
                               //nothing found
                               Log.d(TAG, "nothing found for this user");
```

If this code is executed, the query is successful, but no documents are returned.
If I leave out .whereArrayContains("userUUIDs", "vQn9vbWzTtcsB71hgPBhX2uWBuI3"), one document is returned.

Google Firestore automatically created the index to query for "userUUIDs".

[index created in firestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhXpN.png)

Why are there no documents returned using **whereArrayContains**?

Edit:
The problem seams to exist with all queries.
I added a string *testValue* to *places* and made a **whereEqualTo** Query. The result was the same. After creating an index (automatically via link in the console) the onSuccessListener code was executed, but no document was found.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post database picture instead of structure

Comment: added a screenshot

Comment: You have posted wrong structure here.

Comment: `Collectiongroup` works on subcollection not on child of subcollection i think

Comment: But the collectionGroup itself Returns the expected documents. Only If I add the whereArrayContains there are problems.

Comment: Where does the `userUUIDs` array exist?

Comment: Your code isn't checking for errors on the query.  Add an error handler and log the message.  What does it say?

Comment: I got an onFailureListener there - but it ends up in onSuccessListener, and queryDocumentSnapshots.isEmpty() is true

Comment: I have compared the code with the example: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#listen_to_multiple_documents_in_a_collection... are you sure you should use `get` before `addOnSuccessListener`?

Answer (score 0):

> Why are there no documents returned using whereArrayContains?

Because you most probably didn't create the correct index. **If** the `userUUIDs` exists within the documents from the "places" collection, when running the app you'll find a message like this in the logcat:

> Caused by: io.grpc.StatusException: FAILED_PRECONDITION: The query requires a COLLECTION_GROUP_CONTAINS index for collection places and field userUUIDs. You can create it here: https://console.firebase.google.com/v1/r/project/...

You can simply click on that link or copy, and paste the URL into a web browser and your index will be created automatically.

Comment: Thank you, but I already did that, I added a screenshot of the index.

Comment: Are you sure that `vQn9vbWzTtcsB71hgPBhX2uWBuI3` exists within the array? Can you show us that?